# How do I sort the list of modules by the number of open issues?

Tags: community-official-site

Is there any option to sort the list of modules on drupal.org by the number of issues?

Comment: You could perhaps make your own list programmatically with the drupal.org APIs: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/api

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

The number of issues isn't really relevant because you need to see what type of issues there are (cosmetic / blocking), how actively the module is maintained, how many maintainers, etc.

Big modules can have a lot of issues, but if they are frequently updated it's no problem. If a module has only one (blocking) issue but it isn't resolved due to lack of maintenance than it's worse.